# How to find out if a user click a video to play it

Tags: php, video, youtube, statistics

I run ads on my site which are usually YouTube videos. I would like to find out if a user clicked these videos. I'm basically trying to use this data in a statistics plugin that I'm creating.

I've tried searching many different keywords but I can't really find anything.

I would appreciate it if I could be pointed in the right direction. Any ideas, hints or links are welcomed.

Comment: You need to define what kind of clicking you're trying to track (i.e. what happens when a user clicks).  Many things to do with video interaction fire events, other things might not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mention YouTube I doubt you have control over the URL.

But, if you can control the URL embedded in the video, then I would suggest building a simple redirect script on your server. Make sure the URL contains either the redirect URL or a code representing the URL which would be held in your Data Base. Add a logging function to the redirect script and hey presto.

If you have no control over the URL, then off the top of my head maybe you could implement some client side JS to add an overlay to the video which becomes the click-able element and implement the URL redirect script above. Some methods to get the URL from the video: https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+youtube+URL

Comment: Wait are you tell me to redirect my users ?

Comment: well yes... but you are sending them to the correct link anyway, i'm just suggesting a method to allow you to log the clicks...

Comment: I like your idea of placing an overlay on the video.

Comment: If you use an overlay, it should be noted that, as per the YouTube TOS, it may not interfere with the operation of the clickable YouTube logo in the bottom right hand corner of the video (or the controls, I expect).